# Creating a new command for the Real Part of a Complex Number

Tags: amsmath

I have created the following command: `\renewcommand{\Re}[1]{\operatorname{Re}{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}`

So that I can write, for example: `\Re{w+z}` , and "Re {w+z}" is shown.

The problem is, that I would like to write: `\Re^2{z}` And I would like to get: "Re^2 {z}" just as it can be done with trigonometric functions.

For example: `\sin^2{(x)}` returns "sin^2 (x)" automatically.

The thing is, if I use `\renewcommand{\Re}[2]{\operatorname{Re}^{#1}{\left\{{#2}\right\}}}` ,

I will have to write, for example, `\Re{}{z}` every time I needed "Re {z}" to be shown, which is terrible.

I would like to write `\Re{something}` and get "Re {something}", and also `\Re^p{something}` and get "Re^p {something}" every time needed, for any p.

I am having the same problem with the imaginary part of the complex numbers, but it's just the same thing.

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please note that `just as it can be done with trigonometric functions` is quite misleading and that `\sin^2{(x)}` is really poor notation, in no small part because it suggests to the casual reader that `\sin` is a macro that takes an argument; that's  most decidedly not the case. Unless you like to make a hobby out of code obfuscation, there's no reason not to write `\sin^2(x)`.

Comment: note that `\left\right` and the `{}` around `#1` will both adversly affect the spacing. You could define the `^` modifier with the `e` argument type with `\NewDocumentCommand`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I defined a new operator name using `\DeclareMathOperator{\myRe}{Re}`. Then I used the new operator name in a new command `\myReCommand` that has an optional argument. Not sure if that helps.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For \DeclareMathOperator
\usepackage{amsmath}

% For better versions of \left and \right (\mleft and \mright)
% Thanks to user Mico for the hint.
\usepackage{mleftright}

\DeclareMathOperator{\myRe}{Re}
\newcommand{\myReCommand}[2][]{\ensuremath{\myRe^{#1}\mleft(#2\mright)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \myRe^2(x) + \myRe(x)^2
\end{equation}

\myReCommand{x} \myReCommand[2]{x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Unrelated to LaTeX, I found [this](http://work.colum.edu/%7Ecshaw/old/class_221/trig_exp_note.pdf) about the notation `\sin^2(t)`. In addition, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172760) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932903) for more discussions.

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

Comment: That's just perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your student will not understand.

Anyway, you can first of all get rid of automatic `\left` and `\right` that won't really work.

Here's a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\Re}{e{^}sO{}m}{%
  \operatorname{Re}\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
    {\left\{#4\right\}}
    {\mathopen{#3\{}#4\mathclose{#3\}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Re{z}+\Re^2{z}+\Re[\big]{a(b+c)}+\Re^2[\Big]{u}+\Re^2*{\frac{z}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can specify the exponent after `\Re`, then a `*` would mean automatic sizing; it's better, though, when really needed, to specify the size as shown.

[image]

If you get errors, it means you're running an older version of LaTeX and you can get away by adding

```
\usepackage{xparse}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\oldRe\Re % store the old \Re definition
\DeclareMathOperator{\RealPart}{Re}
\let\oldIm\Im % store the old \Im definition
\DeclareMathOperator{\ImaginaryPart}{Im}

\begin{document}
    % Real and imaginary part command redefinition
\def\Re{\RealPart}
\def\Im{\ImaginaryPart}

\[\Re^2(x)\]
\end{document}
```